# Is it feasible to extract the code assist/completion part from Eclipse and use it in an other editor?

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor, code-completion, code-assist

I often hear how good the code completion, coding assist features of Eclipse are compared to other editors which raises the question if these parts could be separated from the Eclipse code base.

If this part is separated with an API through which it can be told things it needs to know (where are the files of the project,  what are the include paths, etc.) then it can return the necessary information (help for a symbol at the cursor, possible completions, etc.) and any editor (emacs, vim, etc.) can use it.

Why is it not done already? Are these code assist parts tied too tightly to Eclipse internals and they can't be sepaarated easily? Could someone who knows about the internal workings of Eclipe shed some light on this?

Edit: Here's a working setup with SharpDevelop for C#, emacs is the UI and the info comes from the SharpDevelop module. See the screenshot [on this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IdeBridge). Eclipse's completion support could support emacs and other editors similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eclim project tries to solve this problem by interfacing directly with eclipse. Thus at least an headless running eclipse is required. While eclim's focus is afaik the vim integration, there also exist plugins for other editors (emacs, textmate, etc). The communication between eclim and an editor happens through a server interface.

Maybe not exactly what you where looking after, but imho worth a look:

http://www.eclim.org/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for and in the meantime someone else also suggested it [in an other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298300/is-there-a-project-to-bring-advanced-language-support-to-emacs-vim-and-other-edi), but thanks anyway. Someone who's looking for this may get to this question first, so it's helpful if there is a reference here to eclim.

Comment: I stumbled over the following few days ago: https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel   It is the intelligent code completion of Komodo Edit ported to Sublime Text. However: i do not know, if it's better than or not as good as eclim or if it's possible to port it to other editors like TextMate ... But maybe you want to check it out.

Comment: According to the README it doesn't support Java or C++, so it's not as good as Eclim, but it's a nice alternative if someone finds eclipse too heavy as a backend.

Answer (score 0):

The content assist uses an internal model of the Java projects - without this model the content assist cannot work (that effectively).

I am not sure, how tightly is integrated to Eclipse internals, but I do know that it uses the Eclipse Resources API (file system handling) and other features such as Eclipse extensions (new completion providers can be added without modifying the code).

Alltogether, I believe to port this completion engine to other editors the mentioned editors would lose their (in some case relative) simplicity to Eclipse, thus it might not provide the smaller footprint of the mentioned editors - so I don't think, it is feasible to provide such engines effectively for other editors.

Comment: The small footprint is not an issue, memory is cheap these days and the extracted completion engine would not be compiled into the other editor of course. It could be a separate proess with which the editor communicates and simply displays the information returned by the code assist module.

Comment: I see. In this case, I think, it is certainly doable, albeit not trivial. I would look at http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors_contentassist.htm for the programming of content assist - it might give a hint.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. De úgy is mondhatnám, hogy köszi, megnézem. ;)