# Is there a project to bring advanced language support to Emacs, VIM and other editors using the Eclipse codebase?

Tags: vim, emacs, ide, editor

There are lots of questions here about IDEs vs. editors and which is better for modern software development. In the answers a usual point is that Eclipse has much better language support e.g. [for Java](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-java-editor-quickassist.htm) and that other editors lag behind in this respect.

Which brings the qeustion: why play catch up at all? Eclipse will always have more development resources, so  it would make more sense to simply use the code Eclipse has. It could be separated from the Eclipse UI and it could be run in a separate process with which Emacs, Vim and other editors simply talk to when they need information, want to perform intelligent code completion or do some refactoring.

Is there an existing project which attempts to do this? It would be the best of the both worlds: one could use the editor to which one's accustomed to and at the same time the powerful language support provided by Eclipse would also be available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a vim lover I can't speak for emacs. Regarding vim, as far as I know, the only good project that combines eclipse and vim is [eclim](http://eclim.org/). But, considering my background ( I'm a ruby developer with a long Java experience) I would **not** recommend Vim for Java development. Eclipse is very good for Java and I don't like hybrid solutions. The real point is related to teams. It's very difficult to find Java developers that can use Vim in a working environment. So, when I had to choose the tools for a project, I chose Eclipse for Java. If your needs are personal maybe you could do different considerations and would go for eclim.

Comment: Thanks, eclim seems promising and apparently there is an Emacs interface too in development. Regarding the hybrid model: Eclipse may be very good for Java, but I found the interface clumsy, so a combination of Emacs' power and Eclipse's language support would be better for me. If there is a free choice of tools in a project then I'd opt for this.

Comment: Yep. It looks promising. Obviously, It's a personal thing. Editors are like shoes IMHO ;)